# The Fourier Transform of a periodic function and it's series

Tags: fourier-transform, fourier-series

Let $X(f)$ be the Fourier transform of $x(t)$:

$$ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)\,e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t $$

$$ x(t) \triangleq \mathscr{F}^{-1}\Big\{ X(f) \Big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f)\,e^{j 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}f $$

The question here it's how can I mathematically relate the Fourier transform of a function with its Fourier coefficients $c_n$ (complex form)

$$ x(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{j 2 \pi (n/T)t} $$
where
$$ c_n = \frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+T} x(t)\,e^{-j 2 \pi (n/T)t} \ \mathrm{d}t \qquad \qquad -\infty < t_0 < +\infty $$

I mean, it's quite obvious that for a non periodic function $ T\cdot c_n = \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} $

However, if I have $x(t)$ periodic and take $x_m(t)=x(t) \cdot \operatorname{rect}\left( \tfrac{t}{T} \right)$

(that means we take a period of $x(t)$)

$$\mathscr{F}\Big\{ x_m(t) \Big\} = X(\nu) * T \operatorname{sinc}(T \nu)$$

($\nu$ is the frequency variable in Hz)

On the other side we may consider that

$$x_m(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{j 2 \pi (n/T)t} \longleftrightarrow \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x_m(t) \Big\} = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n \delta(\nu-\tfrac{n}{T}) $$

So what I've seen people doing was saying that we could replace $c_n$ for $\frac{1}{T}\mathscr{F}\Big\{ x_m(t) \Big\}$  and then if I have a repeated spectrum in time I can only calculate it's transform and I'll have the amplitudes on the frequency spectrum for each dirac.

I cannot see it mathematically nor can say if it's true.

Comment: you need to fix your mathematical notation.  you are using "$f$" for two different mathematical objects.

Comment: also, do you know how to do $\LaTeX$ markup here?  would you like me to edit your question and show you?

Comment: did i express your question correctly (as you intended), Lucas?  you just can't have two $f$ symbols meaning different things, so i left $f$ as frequency and changed your function to $x(t)$.

Comment: Oh, come on, Robert, what's the harm if Lucas uses $f$ to mean two different things? After all, even you (and Lucas too, I think) use $x_m(t)$ to denote both one period of $x(t)$ and all of $x(t)$ since you equate $x_m(t)$ with the Fourier series expression for $x(t)$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate i saw that too.  but i was trying to translate Lucas's statement of the problem faithfully, but with eliminating one of the two uses of $f$.

Comment: i want Lucas to look at this and maybe polish the question.  i think if he does, maybe the answer will fall out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction, that looks pretty good, sorry I didn't know how to put it in latex. Sorry I took so long to answer.

Comment: That's quite what I asked. The thing is I tried to give a little bit of context before askin how it was replace the coefficient with the fourier transform

Comment: I can see that they are related, but I cannot quite calculate the fourier coefficient from the fourier transform, in my opinion that's false.

Comment: You cannot "see" what the issue is because you are starting from false assumptions,  The break-down occurs  in your last displayed equation where you state that $x_m(t)$ **equals**  $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_n e^{j 2 \pi (n/T)t} $ which in ordinary mathematical discourse means implicitly that equality holds _for all_ $t$.  Not so; equality holds _only_ for  $t \in (-T/2,T/2)$ and not outside this interval, and the Fourier transform of $x_m(t)$ **is not** the impulse train in the frequency domain that you believe it is, but instead a conventional Fourier transform with _no_  impulses.